# Homomorphism defined on a simple group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, simple-groups

### Can anybody please help me with this question???

> Let $G$ and $G'$ be groups with $G$ simple.
>
> Prove that  if $|G| > |G'|$, then the only homomorphism $\varphi : G → G'$ is the trivial one.

Comment: What was the definition of a simple group? And what does that tell about the homomorphisms from a simple group to another group?

Answer (score 3):

Hint: The kernel of any homomorphism $f: G \to G'$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.

Comment: Ha! Wow our answers are practically identical. I'll delete mine since you were first. `:)`